# When attempt to close chatbot, it causes firing the LWC component again

Tags: lightning-web-components, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I have overridden the chatMessage with LWC component in Einstein Bot. I have a requirement to open an article page. Opening page functionality is working fine but when user go other page like home and click the confirm close chat button. LWC method connectedCallback is fired with all previous messages that is used in chatbot. And these cause to open the article page again.

How to control if confirm button is clicked, or is there any other workaround to prevent this problem?

the code snippet:

```
     connectedCallback() {
        if (this.isSupportedUserType(this.userType)) {
          // console.log('userType:> ', this.userType);
          this.messageStyle = `${CHAT_CONTENT_CLASS} ${this.userType}`;
          this.message = this.messageContent.value;
          if (this.isAgent && this.message.startsWith('lwc:articledetail')) {
            const articleUrl = this.message.split(':')[2];
            // console.log('selectedArticleUrl:>', articleUrl);
            // console.log('selected.article.summary:>', this.message.split(':')[3]);
            if (articleUrl) {
              this.goToArticleDetailPage(articleUrl);
            } else {
              this._articleFailMessage = 'I could not find this article detail page';
            }
          }
        ....
        ....
        } else {
          throw new Error(`Unsupported user type passed in: ${this.userType}`);
        }
      }
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Are you able to find out a solution for this? If yes then can you please share it?

Comment: yeah I had found the solution, I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround for the problem I had faced.

```
var  closed = false;
var connectedTime = 0;
export default class ShChatBotBase extends NavigationMixin(BaseChatMessage) {
```

I have added two variable before class

```
disconnectedCallback(){
 closed = true;
}
```

Added disconnectedCallback to set closed true if the user closes the chat

changed connectedCallback to renderedCallback so that each time chatbot renders I can check the closed value and the connected times. If user closed the chat than closed variable becames true and even if messages comes to renderedCallback, they won't be handled.

```
 renderedCallback() {

   if(this.messageContent.value.startsWith('Hi')){
     connectedTime ++;
   }
   if(connectedTime % 2 === 0){
     closed = false;
   }
   if(!closed){
     if (this.isSupportedUserType(this.userType)) {
        this.messageStyle = `${CHAT_CONTENT_CLASS} ${this.userType}`;
        ...
```